# Does the L'Etranger have to be active in order for me to have a 40% increased cloak duration?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-spy

Under the description of the L'Etranger weapon, it says (amongst other things)

> +40% cloak duration.

Does the L'Entranger have to be active in order for this duration effect to apply, or is it a passive effect (in which case I only need to have the L'Entranger in my loadout for the +40% cloak duration to take effect)?

Comment: "Equipped" typically refers to any item currently in your loadout. "Active" typically refers to the weapon you are currently using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a passive effect and works even if you have your Sapper, Knife, or Disguise Kit out.

Do be aware that if you use it with the Dead Ringer that the damage mitigation and flickerless cloak time remains at 6.5 seconds even though the cloak is longer than that.

Comment: +1 for the tip about Dead Ringer. I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @AustinMohr Incidentally, the damage reduction is max 6.5 seconds even if you pick up more ammo boxes to extend the cloak length.  Also, since the July 2013 balance updates, any damage you take shortens the damage reduction time but not the cloak time.

Comment: Does this 40% increase apply to the Cloak and Dagger?

Comment: @alexqwx Yes.  It applies to all cloaking devices.

Comment: Incidentally, the passive effect makes it the ideal choice for Medieval Mode, as it's effect still applies even if you can't use the revolver part.

Comment: @Robotnik That sounds like a bug.

Comment: @Powerlord it's a feature until they patch it ;)